# Submit HTML form data as a file / Combine form data + file and send as single file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form with input field like some textfields ,textareas,dropdowns and a file upload field which the user will upload while filling the form i want to send form contents (both form field values + uploaded file) as one file to the server below is a very simplified version of my problem .Say i have the following markup

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="something">
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
  <input type="text" name="email"  id="email">
  <input type="file" name="myFile"   id="myFile">
</form>
```

So now what i want is instead of sending above 2 text fields and a file separately i want them to get embedded in a file and then get sent as a whole.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pEQ0.png)

Note that the server where i am sending is third party and only excepts files also file format is proprietary but nonetheless it still a ASCII plain/text.I realize that it's only possible by AJAX and fileReader API so here is what i have tried

```
 var file;
 $('#myFile').change(function(e){
    file = this.files[0];
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function(event){
        fileData = fr.result;
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);

  $('#myForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();//prevent submit
    var myFile= [$('#username').val(),$('#email').val(),fileData];
    $.ajax({
      url : "some url",
      type: "POST",
      contentType:false,
      processData:false,
      data: myFile;
      success:function(data){ }
    });
 });
```

Issue is that upon form submission no file gets sent .Any help would be greatly appreciated , thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 parts

1. Convert file to string format or serialize it on client side using FileReader API
2. Combine your form values with this string and send them as a file.

**Part one**

I don't know if you have noticed or not but when you use `readAsDataURL()` you don't get the original file byte-stream but its *base64 encoded* version so keeping that in mind change you code to

```
var fileData;
$('#myFile').change(function(e){
    file = this.files[0];
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function(event) {
        encfileData = fr.result;
        startInx = encfileData.indexOf('base64');
        startInx += 7;
        tmp = encfileData.substr(startInx);
        //removes the file MIME header part ie. "data:text/plain;base64," before decoding
        //regex may be preferable
        fileData = atob(tmp); //DECODE
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

So now you have a string containing your file's byte-stream now as you have said  there is some format so depending on that you do whatever manipulation you may need to make it align with the format, since you have mentioned it's plain text format so basic string function are sufficient here.For next part i assume simple colon based CSV format `key1:value1,key2:value2`

**Part Two**

Now to truly create a file out of thin air you can use either [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) or  [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob) but i would suggest using Blob due to its better support.To contain the file you require FormData simply append your blob to it and send

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var txtData = "\n username:"+$("#username").val()+","+"email:"+$("#email").val();
    // NOTE: windows uses \r\n instead of \n for newlines
    var payLoad =  fileData + txtData;  //append text field data to the file data

    var blob = new Blob([payLoad], {type : 'plain/txt'});
    var form = new FormData();
    var fileName = 'combined.txt';    //filename that will be used on server
    form.append('something', blob, fileName);

    $.ajax({
        url: "some url",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form,
        success: function(response){alert(response);}
    });     
});
```

If using php on linux your $_FILES should look something like this

```
Array
(
    [something] => Array
    (
        [name] => combined.txt
        [type] => plain/txt
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpJvSJ94
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 95
    )

)
```

Comment: After finishing with your code corrections i consulted dev. team on the third party app. server and they did find form data inside uploaded file! . That worked really great thanx for your valuable help :)

Answer (score 1):

In form submit you can do as mentioned below for send file with AJAX request

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();//prevent submit

    var form_data = new FormData();                  
    form_data.append('file', $('#myfile').prop('files')[0]);
    form_data.append('username', $("#username").val());
    form_data.append('phone', $("#phone").val());

    $.ajax({
      url : "some url",
      type: "POST",
      contentType:false,
      processData:false,
      data: form_data;
      success:function(data){ }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Note `FormData` objects may not be supported by the browsers the application targets. See [this link](http://caniuse.com/#search=formdata) for more info on general availability.

Comment: Its not public facing website so we can make users use a particular web browser but unfortunately after trying this code i found its no different that a regular ajax upload files sent to server is same as original and text fields    are not in it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're passing sending the wrong variable in your AJAX payload - shouldn't you be sending `fileData` instead of `file`?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload data and files:

**HTML**

```
<form id="data" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
  <input type="text" name="email"  id="email">
  <input type="file" name="myFile"   id="myFile">
</form>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("form#data").submit(function(){

var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

$.ajax({
    url: 'your_url',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data)
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});

return false;
});
```